# SwiftUI: Using @Binding with @Property variable from a protocol

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a ParentView from which I want to pass @Published variable to a Subview, where it will be used as @Bindable.

This works when using MyViewModel like this:

```
class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var soundOn = true
}

struct ParentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var myViewModel: MyViewModel
    var body: some View {
        Subview(soundOn: $myViewModel.soundOn)
    }
}

struct Subview: View {
    @Binding var soundOn: Bool
    var body: some View {
        Image(soundOn ? "soundOn" : "soundOff")
    }
}
```

but I want to reuse Subview for all ViewModels conforming to the HasSoundOnOff protocol.
When using the HasSoundOnOff protocol I can't define @Published inside the protocol and this means ParentView only sees a normal non-@Published variable and can't use $viewModel.soundOn.

```
protocol HasSoundOnOff {
    var soundOn: Bool { get set }
}

class MyViewModel: HasSoundOnOff {
    @Published var soundOn = true
}

struct ParentView<ViewModel: ObservableObject & HasSoundOnOff>: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    var body: some View {
        Subview(soundOn: $viewModel.soundOn) //<----- error: "Expression type 'Binding<_>' is ambiguous without more context" because protocols can't have @Published and therefor soundOn is treated like a non-@Published variable
    }
}
```

I can let MyViewModel inherit from a class that defines the @Published variable, so the following code works:

```
class InheritFromPublishedVarClass: ObservableObject {
    @Published var soundOn = true
}

class MyViewModel: ObservableObject & InheritFromPublishedVarClass {}

struct ParentView<ViewModel: ObservableObject & InheritFromPublishedVarClass>: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    var body: some View {

        Subview(soundOn: $viewModel.soundOn)
    }
}
```

This means I can reuse my @Published variable, but this won't scale since multiple inheritance is not allowed.

This is seriously limiting code reusability for me. There must be a way to achieve this in a more scalable way. 
Any ideas?
A requirement is to have the ParentView take in a Generic ViewModel parameter.

Comment: C++ legacy (multiple inheritance)? No limitations, just rethink your design, use `InheritFromPublishedVarClass` as `HasSoundOnOffBase` very base class, for example. Protocols cannot have stored properties by language design (so no exclusion for @Published, which is just property wrapper around stored property).

Comment: thanks, could you maybe show me an example of this in action?

Answer (score 4):

I don't fully understand why this works, but it appears that if the protocol extends ObservableObject, then the `@ObservedObject` dynamic member lookup works:

```
protocol HasSoundOnOff: ObservableObject {
    var soundOn: Bool { get set }
}
```

Alternatively, you could manually implement the magic behind the `@ObservedObject` and `@StateObject` property wrappers. Specifically, you can tweak your protocol definition to return a Binding, and then you can manually instantiate a Binding.

First, add a corresponding Binding parameter to your protocol:

```
protocol HasSoundOnOff {
    var soundOn: Bool { get set }
    var soundOnBinding: Binding<Bool> { get }
}
```

Second, manually instantiate a Binding:

```
class MyViewModel: ObservableObject, HasSoundOnOff {
    @Published var soundOn = true
    var soundOnBinding: Binding<Bool> {
        Binding(get: { self.soundOn }, set: { self.soundOn = $0 })
    }
}
```

Finally, use your Binding (rather than that of `@ObservedObject`):

```
struct ParentView<ViewModel: ObservableObject & HasSoundOnOff>: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    var body: some View {
        Subview(soundOn: viewModel.soundOnBinding)
    }
}
```

SwiftUI's property wrappers just don't seem to play very well with protocol inheritance. Hopefully future updates to Swift, such as [this proposal](https://forums.swift.org/t/property-wrapper-requirements-in-protocols/33953), will provide more compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not use

```
@EnvironmentObject var myViewModel: MyViewModel
```

in your views where you need access to it.  Then use it as

```
myViewModel.soundOn
```

you won't need to pass it across Views as Bindings, as you will have access to soundOn in any view that you declare your @EnvironmentObject in.

Comment: the whole thing is about using MyViewModel1, MyViewModel2, MyViewModel3... and only one Subview. I would need to create Subview 3 times for your solution to work

Answer (score 0):

You could use a protocol extension for this. Note that the protocol also has to conform to `ObservableObject` but in your use case this should be fine.

```
protocol HasSoundOnOff: ObservableObject {
    var soundOn: Bool { get set }
}

extension HasSoundOnOff {
    var soundOnBinding: Binding<Bool> {
        Binding(get: { self.soundOn }, set: { self.soundOn = $0 })
    }
}

class MyViewModel: HasSoundOnOff {
    @Published var soundOn = true
}
```

From here, you just need to reference the binding wrapper in the protocol extension. Meanwhile, you just need to confirm to the actual protocol in your implementation.

```
struct ParentView<ViewModel: HasSoundOnOff>: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    var body: some View {
        Subview(soundOn: viewModel.soundOnBinding)
    }
}
```

Comment: We tried this way and it ended up being so complex tracking data and the view model we reverted a very different way of doing view models.